# On the proof of Meusnier's Theorem: Direction of derivative of unit velocity vector

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

In Andrew Pressley's "Elementary Differential Geometry" (second edition) on page 168 he gives a proof of Meusnier's Theorem, which is stated as follows:

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathbf p$ be a point on the surface $\mathcal S$ and let $\mathbf v$ be a unit tangent vector to $\mathcal S$ at $\mathbf p$. Let $\Pi_\theta$ be the plane containing the line through $\mathbf p$ parallel to $\mathbf v$ and making an angle $\theta$ with the tangent plane $T_{\mathbf p}\mathcal S$, and assume that $\Pi_\theta$ is not parallel to $T_{\mathbf p}\mathcal S$. Suppose that $\Pi_\theta$ intersects $S$ in a curve with curvature $\kappa_\theta$. Then $\kappa_\theta\sin\theta$ is independent of $\theta$.

The proof is short, and begins as follows:

> Assume that $\gamma_\theta$ is a unit-speed parametrization of the curve of intersection of $\Pi_\theta$ and $\mathcal S$. Then at $\mathbf p$, $\gamma_\theta' = \pm\mathbf v$, so $\gamma_\theta''$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf v$ $\underline{\text{and is parallel to $\Pi_\theta$}}$.

My question is about the underlined statement. How do we know that $\gamma_\theta''$ lies on $\Pi_\theta$? Looking at the diagram given, it seems obvious, in the sense that $\gamma_\theta''$ is parallel to the principle normal to $\gamma_\theta$, which, along with $\gamma_\theta'$ forms the basis for the oscullating plane, which also "looks" like the plane $\Pi_\theta$, but other than that heuristic argument I can't formalize why $\gamma_\theta''$ should lie on $\Pi_\theta$. I'm sure its easy, I'm just missing the obvious. Can anyone help out?

Comment: $ \gamma_\theta $ by definition is a planar curve lying in the plane $ \Pi_\theta $. Therefore the normal $ \gamma'' $ will be parallel to the plane $ \Pi_\theta $.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I've forgotten the mechanics of planar curves, I'll have to go back and check them, but for the sake of future readers looking at this question could you type up your response in an answer?

Comment: There's not too much to remember :) if you have a planar curve $ ( x(t), y(t) ) $, no derivatives will give you a z component. More generally, if $ \gamma $ is in a plane then $ \gamma \cdot n = d $ where $ n $ and $ d $ define the plane. Then differentiate twice.

Comment: You have a typo in the statement. You never defined $\mathbf v$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formal typed answer 5 years later. Notice that the curve $\gamma$ lies in a $\textbf{plane}$, say $S$, then the plane equation for $S$ can assume to be $ax+by+cz = d$, where $a,b,c$ not all 0.

Now, suppose $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to S$ is parametrized by arc-length: $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ .To show $\gamma ''$ is parallel to $S$, it suffices to show $<\gamma'', N> = 0$ where $N$ is the unit normal of $S$. Since in $S$, $ax(t)+by(t)+cz(t)=d$, differentiating both sides we have $ax'+by'+cz'=0$. This implies the unit normal is $\displaystyle{N = (\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}})}$, which is a constant. By normal is perpendicular to tangent plane, $<N,\gamma'> = 0$. Differentiate it we have $<N',\gamma'>+<N, \gamma''>=0$. Therefore $<N,\gamma''>=0$.